# JSON response item is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, undefined, response

I got a problem with showing a text of a JSON response:
I've the following response:

```
{
  "status": false,
  "msg": "Achtung: Zeile 2 enthält ungültige Zeichen!",
  "csv_data": []
}
```

And now I want to log the "msg" text in the console for test purposes.
That's what I've tried:

```
[...], success: function (file, response) {
        // this response works and logs the above JSON
        console.dir(response);

        // the following return "undefined"
        console.log(response.msg);
```

What is the problem here? I can't find the fault...
Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: Try `typeof response`, I bet it's not an object, you probably need to deserialize it first

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes I also feel like response coming as string ...@Philipp try to deserialize using JSON.parse(response) and then check

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was actually thinking along similar lines that it's not what's expected but I assumed it might actually be an array - `[{   "status": false, "msg": "Achtung: Zeile 2 enthält ungültige Zeichen!",   "csv_data": [] }]`

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answers! Sadly nothing is helping so far...
@CertainPerformance the `typeof` returns "string"

Comment: @Rajiv if I do json.parse the typeof says it's an object

`var test = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(typeof test);`

Comment: @Philipp if typeof returns string then parsing should work .. post your actual response string

Comment: I parsed it to the json and got it working. Thank you guys and have a nice day! :)

`var test = JSON.parse(response);
   console.log(test.txt);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's stringifyed. Try:

```
JSON.parse(response).msg
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
response.data.msg
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is of type string. you have to parse it as json:

```js
let response = '{"status": false, "msg": "Achtung: Zeile 2 enthält ungültige Zeichen!", "csv_data": []}'


let json_response = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(json_response.msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the response if it's not an object else do nothing

```js
response = typeof response === 'object'? response: JSON.parse(response)
```

OR

```js
try {
  response = JSON.parse(response)
} catch(err) {
  //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Completing the answer, following [AZ_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381809/az) 's lead,

```
const finalResponse = typeof response === 'object'? response: JSON.parse(response);
console.log(finalResponse.msg);
```